# Websocket request error on Cloud Run on GKE

Tags: google-cloud-run

Just deployed a cloud run on GKE (version 1.13.6-gke.6) service following this: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying

Code were similar to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-websockets-and-session-affinity
and it worked on my local

but my requests (via curl and javascript) return 503 error:

```
< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
< content-length: 85
content-length: 85
< content-type: text/plain
content-type: text/plain
< date: Fri, 14 Jun 2019 05:07:37 GMT
date: Fri, 14 Jun 2019 05:07:37 GMT
< server: istio-envoy
server: istio-envoy
< connection: close
connection: close
```

Any idea what am I missing out?

Comment: Cloud Run on GKE does not support in-bound WebSockets. Your application can connect out-bound (create connections). What port is your service listening to? It must be port 8080 ($PORT). https://github.com/ahmetb/cloud-run-faq#are-websockets-supported-on-cloud-run

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the doc. I thought it's not supported on cloud run but we can do it on gke

Comment: "Cloud Run on GKE" and "GKE" are not the same.